# Change List<Mono<List<A>>> to Mono<List<A>> while staying inside Mono

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to stay within Mono to not make any blocking calls, and I can't find a way to change my List<Mono<List>> to Mono<List succesfully (without using Flux)

The solution with Flux looks like this, but it is eager from what I see in `fromIterable` and `flatMapSequential`:

```java
private Mono<ImageResponse> getImages(List<Long> materialNumbers, String method, List<String> usages) {
        Collection<List<Long>> materialNumbersPartitioned = partition(materialNumbers);

        List<Mono<List<ArticleImage>>> foundArticleImagesAsMonos = materialNumbersPartitioned
                .stream()
                .map(materialNumbersFromPartition -> createGetRequestBuilder(method, materialNumbersFromPartition, usages))
                .map(reactiveHttpClient::get)
                .map(this::getArticleImagesFromResponse)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Mono.zip(foundArticleImagesAsMonos.stream())

        Flux<List<ArticleImage>> mergedMonos = Flux
                .fromIterable(foundArticleImagesAsMonos)
                .flatMapSequential(Function.identity());

        return mergedMonos
                .next()
                .map(foundArticleImages -> new ImageResponse(true, foundArticleImages, null));
    }
```

The solution without Flux looks like this but I am getting an error because of the unchecked cast. Can someone help me out?

```java
private Mono<ImageResponse> getImages(List<Long> materialNumbers, String method, List<String> usages) {
        Collection<List<Long>> materialNumbersPartitioned = partition(materialNumbers);

        List<Mono<List<ArticleImage>>> foundArticleImagesAsMonos = materialNumbersPartitioned
                .stream()
                .map(materialNumbersFromPartition -> createGetRequestBuilder(method, materialNumbersFromPartition, usages))
                .map(reactiveHttpClient::get)
                .map(this::getArticleImagesFromResponse)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Mono<List<ArticleImage>> foundArticleImages = flattenMonos(foundArticleImagesAsMonos);
        return foundArticleImages.map(o -> new ImageResponse(true, o, null));

    }

    public Mono<List<ArticleImage>> flattenMonos(List<Mono<List<ArticleImage>>> listOfMonos) {
        return Mono.zip(listOfMonos, objectArray -> Arrays
                .stream(objectArray)
                .map(object -> (List<ArticleImage>) object) << this unchecked cast
                .flatMap(List::stream) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

Comment: this gives me a Mono<List<List<ArticleImage>> ... because of the collectList()

Comment: you can always flatMap the List<List<>> part.